# If a convex cone K and a linear subspace L are such that $K\cap L=\{0\}$, is it true that the intersection of their polars has a non-zero vector?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, convex-cone

A bit more details: I'm trying to prove that if the first condition holds, then the following statement is also true:
$$\exists z\neq 0 \text{ such that }z\in K°\cap L^\perp.$$

That second condition allows me to use other results I have on the context of my problem and get some really nice results. Notice that the polar of a linear subspace is its orthogonal complement. My intuition tells me it's true, and is easy to see that in $d=2$ that is the case. However, I have not been able to prove it. I believe some variation of Farka's Lemma might be useful. I also tried to use the fact that the intersection of polar of cones is the polar of their Minkowski sum ($K_1^°\cap K_2^°=(K_1\oplus K_2)^°$), also to no success.

Any help is welcomed and appreciated.

Edit: As Theo commented, there is an easy counterexample. I should add the restriction that $K$ is not a subspace.

Comment: What if $K$ and $L$ are both subspaces that orthogonal complements? Then $K \cap L = \{0\}$, and $K^\circ \cap L^\perp = K^\perp \cap L^\perp = L \cap K = \{0\}$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's a good point. I should add that on my specific case, $K$ is not a linear subspace (thou it may not be pointed). I'll modify the question.